# Speed of height of water in cube by entering cylinder

Tags: calculus

Consider a cube with sidelength $3$ containing water of volume $\frac{27}{2}$

A solid cylinder of radius $1$ and height $2$ is  placed inside the cube so that it's top face aligns with the top face of the cube. This cylinder then descends into the water.

Denote $x$ as **the distance between two *parallel* top faces of the cube and cylinder** and $h$ as *the height of the water level relative to the bottom of the cylinder*. Since the volume of water is invariant,
$$(3-2-x)9 + h(9-\pi) = \frac{27}{2} \ (1)$$

If $x'(t)=1$ for all $t\in (s-\epsilon,s+\epsilon)$ where $h(s)=1$, then taking the derivative gives
$$ h'(t) = \frac{ 9 }{9-\pi } $$

To calculate $h'(t)$, we can use a different approach that instead considers the displacement of water. If the cylinder descends by for $a$ seconds starting at time $t$, then we have
$$ \pi \bigg( x(t+a)- x(t) \bigg) = (9-\pi ) \bigg(h(t+a)-h(t)\bigg)\ (2) $$
$$\pi = \pi x'(t) = (9-\pi) h'(t)$$
$$\ h'(t) = \frac{\pi }{9-\pi } $$

Why are two results different ?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a picture? I'm having problems understanding $x$ and $h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation $2$ is incorrect.

When you push the cylinder down by $x(t+a)-x(t)$ units, $h$ is increased by the displacement of water **and the pushing down of the cylinder**. As a result, our equation should be
$$h(t+a)-h(t)=\frac{\pi}{9-\pi}\left(x(t+a)-x(t)\right)+\left(x(t+a)-x(t)\right)$$
The first term on the RHS is the term you got from the water being displaced. The second term is the increase of the height of the water due to the fact that the bottom of the cylinder is being pushed down. This simplifies to
$$h(t+a)-h(t)=\left(\frac{\pi}{9-\pi}+1\right)\left(x(t+a)-x(t)\right)$$
$$h'(t)=\frac{9}{9-\pi}x'(t)$$